# Left-join failing because of date formats in R

Tags: r, many-to-many, left-join, read.csv, janitor

I have [one csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S0C1XtVp8md_q_zHqlZy27y_iXsjy_Ad/view?usp=sharing) that contains 2 columns, one is weekly dates and the other one is daily dates for each day of every week.

In [another csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13SyAoO8AkyGpbi_BM7BDkyOw8HaAUsEk/view?usp=sharing) I have weekly data and I want to make a copy of the csv, with daily data and duplicating the same value for each day of that week, getting something like the below:

```
 OBS  DailyDate column1 column2
1   2008-01-07 2008-01-07      5      5
2   2008-01-07 2008-01-08      5      5
3   2008-01-07 2008-01-09      5      5
4   2008-01-07 2008-01-10      5      5
5   2008-01-07 2008-01-11      5      5
6   2008-01-07 2008-01-12      5      5
7   2008-01-07 2008-01-13      5      5
8   2008-01-14 2008-01-14      20     20
9   2008-01-14 2008-01-15      20     20
10  2008-01-14 2008-01-16      20     20
11  2008-01-14 2008-01-17      20     20
12  2008-01-14 2008-01-18      20     20
13  2008-01-14 2008-01-19      20     20
14  2008-01-14 2008-01-20      20     20
```

The problem I am getting is that when trying to do so with a left_join, I get a dataframe with all NA's, instead of each value duplicated for everyday of the week.

I believe the problem is something about the date formats (for other csv's it is all working as expected).

To solve that, I've tried converting to date formats with different functions but even if the date columns seem to be in the same date formats after reading the csv, the join fails.

```
str(dates_master)
'data.frame':   4053 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ OBS      : Date, format: "2008-01-07" "2008-01-07" "2008-01-07" "2008-01-07" ...
 $ DailyDate: Date, format: "2008-01-07" "2008-01-08" "2008-01-09" "2008-01-10" ...

str(data_test)
'data.frame':   164 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ OBS    : Date, format: "2015-12-21" "2015-12-28" "2016-01-04" "2016-01-11" ...
 $ column1: num  323 974 528 375 351 ...
 $ column2: num  240 660 412 316 300 ...
```

Therefore, I thought that if I saved the dates in the csv's with a non-date format (e.g. 42464) and then I use the janitor package to convert to date it would solve the issue, but it doesn't.

The code I am using is this one:

```
data_test <- read.csv("C:/Users/me/Documents/monthly_and_daily_data/test.csv")
data_test$OBS <- janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(data_test$OBS)

dates_master <- read.csv("C:/Users/me/Documents/monthly_and_daily_data/dates_master.csv")
dates_master$OBS <- janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(dates_master$OBS)
dates_master$DailyDate <- janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(dates_master$DailyDate)

data_test_daily <- dates_master %>%
  left_join(data_test, by = "OBS", relationship = "many-to-many") %>%
     # left_join(data_test, by = "OBS", suffix = c(".daily", ".monthly")) %>%
      # left_join(data_test, by = c("OBS" = "OBS"), suffix = c(".daily", ".monthly")) %>%
  select(-OBS) %>%
  rename(OBS = DailyDate)
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
As suggested in the comments, please find below and example of both of my datasets:

```
> dput(head(dates_master))
structure(list(OBS = c(39454L, 39454L, 39454L, 39454L, 39454L, 
39454L), DailyDate = 39454:39459), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = 
"data.frame")
> dput(head(data_test))
structure(list(OBS = c(39454L, 39454L, 39454L, 39454L, 39454L, 
39454L), column1 = c(323.1428571, 974.3571429, 527.9285714, 375.0714286, 
351.3571429, 359.2142857), column2 = c(239.9880952, 660.202381, 
412.047619, 315.744186, 300.2325581, 280.3837209)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: please share the code for this data, not just formated tables. You can use `dput`

Comment: If the problem is "date formats", then your dates probably aren't stored as dates, they're stored as characters.

Comment: @GuedesBF you can find the csv's in the links provided - there is no code to create that data

Comment: Paula, please check some useful tutorials and guidelines, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You should make it as easy as possible for people trying to help to reproduce your data and errors. usually, this means providing the actual dataset is better than providing multi-step upstream code. `dput` is meant for that. Try to call the following, code so you understand the use of dput: `dput(head(dates_master))`. You can paste this output into the question, allong with `dput(head(desired_output))`

Comment: This gets us the chance to reproduce your data, as we do not have access to your local files, and we may not be willing to take the effort into downloading the data.

Comment: There are no overlapping dates in the sample data you provided so it's not surprising that you would get NA values. Are you sure there are overlapping dates in your actual data?

Comment: Yes, there are. I'll amend the example

Comment: If I run `left_join(dates_master, data_test, by = "OBS", relationship = "many-to-many")` with your sample data, I get 36 rows with no `NA`s. It's much easier to help you if the code and data in the question reproduce the misbehavior you're citing.

Comment: @r2evans many thanks for your comment. Both of the csv's are provided in the links. One of them has 4053 observations and the other one has 164, so I thought it would be better if I attached them like that, instead of copy and paste them, that's why the sample data in the question is just an example that reproduce the data. If you're not getting any error I'll investigate further to see where does the error come from. Thanks again for your comment

Comment: With your larger data (the links you provided), if I do `table(dates_master$OBS %in% data_test$OBS)`, I get 2905 false and 1148 true, so you have many more `OBS` in the `dates_master` that do not match your `data_test`. Since you're doing `left_join(dates_master, data_test, by="OBS", ...)`, then you're going to get 2905 rows with `NA`s in the new columns, since there is nothing to put there. (Conversely, all of `data_test$OBS` are found in `dates_master$OBS`.)

Comment: @r2evans that it's fine, because I'll then replace those NA's with zeros. The problem is that for those dates that are in both datasets I'm also getting NA's everywhere

Comment: I am not seeing that.

Comment: Okay, many thanks for confirming. I'll investigate further then because I'm not sure what's going on in my end. Thank you!